# Stack Exchange sites currently do not work in Firefox due to broken OCSP stapling

Tags: bug, ssl, firefox

As of a few minutes (hours?) ago, all SE sites except chat present a TLS error in Firefox:

> An error occurred during a connection to superuser.com. A required TLS feature is missing. Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_REQUIRED_TLS_FEATURE_MISSING

A bit of searching suggests that this occurs when a certificate specifies OCSP must-staple but there is no stapled response. [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=superuser.com) seems to [support](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=superuser.com&s=151.101.65.69) this conclusion.

Toggling `security.ssl.enable_ocsp_must_staple` in Firefox from its default of `true` to `false` allows access to the site again (please don't actually do this! I only did so to test it!), again suggesting a stapling issue.

I have at least one other person in chat confirming this is an issue in Firefox. It currently does work in Chrome, which is presumably not honouring the must-staple.